# Font Antialiasing vary in textarea in Flex 3.5

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, antialiasing, flashbuilder4

A weird bug occurs when displaying text, the antialiasing seems to change over the span of the textarea as shown in the image. Notice the "x" on the bottom left side compared to the "u" in the upper right side.

[image: Textarea antialiasing bug in flex]

I'm using Arial thats embedded and i've tried with both advancedAntialiasing set to false or true, but this bug still occurs.

I'm using the Flex 3.5 SDK in Flash Builder 4.0. 
The player from which i've taken the screenshot is is Flash Player 11

My question is how is this possible, and what can i do to remove the weird behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour was due to a z coordinate set to the textarea. Slightly surprising effect. Setting the textarea z to 0 removed any odd blur.